# Cannot install Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, wubi

I got a new computer and am looking to dual-boot Ubuntu and windows 7.

I have my partition made (50gb), and my 64bit boot disk made but when I try booting from it I just get a black screen, with the underscore. I can still use my old boot disk with version 11 of Ubuntu but its 32bit. I have tried looking for a solution, I extracted the .iso to a folder and I get the error "the version of this file is not compatible with the version of windows. etc..." when I run the wubi.exe, but yet the old 32bit wubi.exe still runs when I do the same thing.

I would like to install the 64bit version now but I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install Ubuntu 14.04 using wubi because they aren't compatible.  You need to [create a Bootable USB stick with the Ubuntu ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Comment: he is saying that the livecd that he burned does not launch, not that he desperately needs to use wubi